# Prove that $\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \binom{m}{n}=0$.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

The problem from the statement is the hardest part of the problem A. 810 from [KöMaL contest November 2021](https://www.komal.hu/feladat?a=honap&h=202111&t=mat&l=en) (the deadline was 10 December).
After the deadline, I noticed that if $r_0=1$:
$$\begin{align}  \sum_{n=0}^m r_n&=\sum_{t=0}^m\sum_{n=t}^m\frac{(-1)^t}{(t+1)!}\binom{n}t\\&=
\sum_{t=0}^m\frac{(-1)^t}{(t+1)!}\sum_{n=t}^m
\binom{n}{t}\\&=\sum_{t=0}^m\frac{(-1)^t}{(t+1)!}\binom{m+1}{t+1}. \end{align} $$
Therefore the KöMaL problem is equivalent to
$$\begin{align}  &\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^m r_n=1\Leftrightarrow\\&\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{t=0}^m\frac{(-1)^t}{(t+1)!}\binom{m+1}{t+1}=1\Leftrightarrow\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{t=1}^{m+1}\frac{(-1)^t}{t!}\binom{m+1}t=-1 \end{align} $$
which equivalent to

> $\displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{m}
> \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \binom{m}{n} = 0$

and I cannot prove this affirmation.

**My ideas:**

1. To study the function $f_m:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},$ $f_m(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^m
   (-1)^n\binom{m}{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$.
2. To use Cauchy product of two series.

Comment: $(1-1)^m=\sum_{n=0}^m\binom{m}{n}(-1)^n=0$  Your expression looks funny.

Comment: Should the series start at $n=1$?

Comment: If you include $n=0$ then the limit appears correct

Comment: The plot in the deleted answer post below was still of some value, so I put it here as well for others to see it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SuZI.png

Comment: @FShrike You are right. It was my mistake.

Comment: The sum is $\Bbb E(-2)^X/X!$ for $X\sim\operatorname{B}(m,\,1/2)$. The usual Gaussian approximation for large $m$, clustering $X$ within $O(\sqrt{m})$ of $m/2$, feels like the beginning of a handwaving motivation of the desired limit.

Comment: this one might help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830604/is-it-possible-solely-with-the-function-fx-sum-n0-a-nxn-to-obtain-t

Comment: These are the values of [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) $L_n(1)$. The generating function is $e^{-t/(1 - t)}/(1 - t)$, which has an essential pole at $t = 1$. This shows that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{|L_n(1)|} = 1$, which unfortunately is not enough to conclude.

Comment: @WhatsUp $$
L_n (1) = \sqrt {\frac{e}{{\pi \sqrt n }}} \sin \left( {2\sqrt n  + \frac{\pi }{4}} \right) + \mathcal{O}(n^{ - 3/4} )
$$

Comment: Interesting question! Can you please elaborate a bit on where you found it? Is it some part of a bigger problem you are working on?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Exactly. In fact, it is the hardest part of a problem (A. 810) from KoMaL contest November 2021 (the deadline was 10 December). After the deadline, I reduced that the problem to this question, and I ask this question on MSE, thinking it's something quite known.

Comment: I checked the original problem, and it seems easier than what is asked here. So I suspect that you fell into the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @SangchulLee Possible. Next time I will give more details about the sources of my questions. If the problem A810 is really easier, can you give me some hints that could lead to a solution without using this question, or I have to ask another question on MSE? (at KoMaL category A there are not always solutions on the site)

Comment: @user914367, Providing contexts and backgrounds always helps other users. By the way, my initial impression might be wrong, and I actually see how that problem is related to your question. What I found was that, if we assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r_n$ converges (where $r_n$ is the sequence defined in [KoMaL](https://www.komal.hu/feladat?a=honap&h=202111&t=mat&l=en#A810)), then its value must be zero. And then I begin to realize that showing the convergence of the series is not an easy task at all.

Comment: @user914367 Note that the sequence $r_n$ in KöMaL is not exactly the same as the one in your question.

Comment: I suggest you move the information (about source of problem) contained in comments into your question. People may not read all comments.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok.

Comment: @Gary I know that. But the problem from KoMaL reduces to this question by using the identity $\sum_{n=k}^m \binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$.

Comment: @Gary A more detailed explanation of the previous comment is here: if we define $r_0=1$ we have $\sum_{n=0}^mr_n=\sum_{n=0}^m\sum_{t=0}^n \frac{(-1)^t}{(t+1)!}=\sum_{t=0}^m\sum_{n=t}^m\frac{(-1)^t}{(t+1)!}\binom{n}{t}=\sum_{t=0}^m \frac{(-1)^t}{(t+1)!}\sum_{n=t}^m \binom{n}{t}=\sum_{t=0}^m\frac{(-1)^t}{(t+1)!}\binom{m+1}{t+1}$. Therefore the KöMaL problem is equivalent to $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^m r_n=1\iff\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{t=0}^m \frac{(-1)^t}{(t+1)!}\binom{m+1}{t+1}=1\iff \lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{t=1}^{m+1}\frac{(-1)^t}{t!}\binom{m+1}{t}=-1$ which is the MSE question.

Comment: @user914367, Again, it is a good idea to include your explanation to the body of your question so it is better exposed!

Comment: @ShangchulLee I edited the body of the question. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^m {(-1)^n}{(m-n)!}\dbinom{m}{n}$ is the [number of ways to return $m$ hats to $m$ men with the condition that no one gets his own hat](https://appliedcombinatorics.org/book/s_inclusion-exclusion_derangements.html). Then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^m {(-1)^n}{(m-n)!}{\dbinom{m}{n}}^2$ is the number of ways to return the hats with *Condition X*. Can you work out what *Condition X* is? Then the series in the original question is the probability that *Condition X* is met, as $m$ approaches infinity.

Comment: @Dan Notice that $\sum_{n=0}^m (-1)^n (m-n)!\binom{m}{n}^2=\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \binom{m}{n}\cdot m!$ is not exactly the expression from the statement (which is $\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \binom{m}{n}$).

Comment: @user914367 Note the word "probability" in my comment. We divide by m!, which is the total number of ways the hats can be given to the men.

Comment: @Dan, OP's sum takes negative values for infinitely many $m$'s. So I am skeptical about probabilistic approach.

Comment: @SangchulLee Probably Dan's idea is to write $|I_m|=\frac1{m!}\left|\sum_{n=0}^m(-1)^n(m-n)!\binom{m}{n}^2\right|$ as a probability and then prove that $\lim_{m \to \infty} |I_m| = 0$, which would solve the problem ($I_m=\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\binom{m}{n}$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**New Answer.** Let $I_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \binom{n}{k}$ be the sum in OP, and let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} I_n(x) z^n$ be the generating function of $(I_n)$. Then by Fubini's theorem<sup>1)</sup>, for $|z| < 1$,

\begin{align*}
f(z)
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2} n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) z^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) z^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^{k+1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} e^{-\frac{z}{1-z}}
= \frac{e}{1-z} e^{-\frac{1}{1-z}}.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, starting from the above formula and using Fubini's theorem<sup>2)</sup> again,

\begin{align*}
f(z)
&= e \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}} \\
&= e \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k!)^2} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^k e^{-(1-z)t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= e \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(1-z)t} \biggl( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k!)^2} t^k \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= e \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{zt} e^{-t} J_0(2\sqrt{t}) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \biggl( e \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} J_0(2\sqrt{t}) \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr) z^n,
\end{align*}

where $J_0(\cdot)$ is the [Bessel function of the first kind of order $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1). This shows that

$$ I_n = e \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} J_0(2\sqrt{t}) \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

Now the desired claim follows from $\lim_{x\to\infty} J_0(x) = 0$ and the next lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $g : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous and satisfies $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 0$. Then
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = 0. $$

Note that this is an instance of the [Abelian theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_and_Tauberian_theorems#Abelian_theorems), which roughly tells that the limit of "averaged function" is the same as the limit of the original function.

*Proof of Lemma.* It is clear that $g$ is bounded on $[0, \infty)$. Let $M$ be a bound of $g$. Also, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, fix $R > 0$ such that $|g(x)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $x \geq R$. Then

\begin{align*}
\left| \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right|
\leq \int_{0}^{R} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} |g(t)| \, \mathrm{d}t + \varepsilon \int_{R}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} \, \mathrm{d}t
\leq \frac{R^n e^{-R}}{n!} M + \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

So by letting $\limsup$ as $n\to\infty$,

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right| \leq \varepsilon. $$

Since $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, the desired conclusion follows. $\square$

---

<sup>1) Here, Fubini's theorem is applicable because
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) z^n \right|
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \frac{|z|^k}{(1-|z|)^{k+1}}
< \infty. $$</sup>

<sup>2) Here, Fubini's theorem is applicable because
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^k}{(k!)^2} \cdot t^k e^{-(1-z)t} \right| \, \mathrm{d}t
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k!)^2} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^k e^{-(1-\operatorname{Re}z)t} \, \mathrm{d}t
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \frac{1}{(1-\operatorname{Re}z)^{k+1}} < \infty. $$
and
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{(zt)^n e^{-t}}{n!} J_0(2\sqrt{t}) \right| \, \mathrm{d}t
\leq \Bigl( \sup |J_0| \Bigr) \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{|z|t}e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t < \infty. $$</sup>

---

**Old Answer.** Let $I_m := \sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \binom{m}{n}$. Then the generating function of $(I_m)$ is given by

$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z} e^{1 + \frac{1}{z-1}} $$

for $|z| < 1$, confirming **@Stefan Lafon**'s observation independently. From this,

$$
I_n
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z| = 0^+} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \, \mathrm{d}z
\qquad \biggl(= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z| = r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \, \mathrm{d}z
\quad \text{for any } 0 < r \ll 1 \biggr)
$$

However, since $f(z)$ is analytic near $\infty$, we may think of the above contour integral as the negative of the contour integral enclosing the "exterior" of $|z| =r$. Then by the residue theorem, it follows that

\begin{align*}
I_n
= -\mathop{\underset{z=1}{\mathrm{Res}}} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}
\stackrel{(w=z-1)}= -\mathop{\underset{w=0}{\mathrm{Res}}} \frac{f(w+1)}{(w+1)^{n+1}} 
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w| = 0^+} \frac{e^{1 + \frac{1}{w}} }{w (w+1)^{n+1}} \, \mathrm{d}w 
\end{align*}

Now by invoking the formula

$$ \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^n e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t, \tag{$\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$} $$

it follows that

\begin{align*}
I_n
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w| = 0^+} \frac{e^{1 + \frac{1}{w}} }{w} \biggl( \frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^n e^{-(w+1)t} \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}w \\
&= e \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} \biggl( \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w| = 0^+} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{w} - tw} }{w} \, \mathrm{d}w \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= e \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} \biggl( \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w| = 0^+} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{t}(\xi - \xi^{-1})} }{\xi} \, \mathrm{d}\xi \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}t \tag{$w\mapsto \xi/\sqrt{t}$} \\
&= e \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} J_0(2\sqrt{t}) \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{*}
\end{align*}

where we utilized the [generating function of $J_{\nu}$'s](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12) to evaluate the inner residue in the last step.

Now, considering that the function $t \mapsto t^ne^{-t}/n!$ is concentrated near $t = n$, $\text{(*)}$ suggests that $I_n$ is asymptotically $e J_0(2\sqrt{n})$, confirming **@Gary**'s observation $I_n \asymp J_0(2\sqrt{n})$ in the now-deleted answer.

Now we justify this heuristics and conclude the proof.

**Proof 1. - Hard analysis.** Since $J_0$ is bounded, we may bound $|I_n|$ by

\begin{align*}
|I_n|
&\leq e \biggl( \sup_{[0,\infty)} |J_0| \biggr) \int_{0}^{n/2} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} \, \mathrm{d}t
+ e \biggl( \sup_{[\sqrt{2n},\infty)} |J_0| \biggr) \int_{n/2}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

Since $t \mapsto t^n e^{-t}$ is increasing for $t \in [0, n]$, we can further bound this by

\begin{align*}
|I_n|
&\leq e \biggl( \sup_{[0,\infty)} |J_0| \biggr)  \int_{0}^{n/2} \frac{(n/2)^n e^{-n/2}}{n!} \, \mathrm{d}t
+ e \biggl( \sup_{[\sqrt{2n},\infty)} |J_0| \biggr) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n e^{-t}}{n!} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= e \biggl( \sup_{[0,\infty)} |J_0| \biggr) \frac{(n/2)^{n+1}e^{-n/2}}{n!} + e \biggl( \sup_{[\sqrt{2n},\infty)} |J_0| \biggr).
\end{align*}

However, since $J_0(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ and $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \, n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n}$ as $n\to\infty$, it follows that the above bound converges to $0$:

$$ \frac{(n/2)^{n+1}e^{-n/2}}{n!} \sim \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \frac{e^{n/2}}{2^n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0 $$

and

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{[\sqrt{2n},\infty)} |J_0|
= \limsup_{x\to\infty} |J_0(x)|
= 0. $$

Therefore $I_n$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

**Proof 2. - Using probability theory.** Let $T_1, T_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ variables. Using this, $\text{(*)}$ can be recast as

$$ I_n = e \mathbf{E}[J_0(2\sqrt{T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_{n+1}})]. $$

However, by an application of SLLN, we find that $T_1 + \cdots + T_{n+1} \to \infty$ almost surely. Therefore by the bounded convergence theorem,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} I_n = e \mathbf{E}\Bigl[ \lim_{n\to\infty} J_0(2\sqrt{T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_{n+1}}) \Bigr] = 0. $$

Comment: +1 Nice answer! Note that your integral formula is a special case of https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.10.E9 and is consistent with the fact that $I_n = L_n(1)$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you for the reference! Anyway, I actually visited that page when I was scrounging around DMLF in search of some nice integral representation of $L_n(1)$, so I feel dumb that I missed that formula and ended up redoing all the calculations by myself.

Comment: I thought about using it in an answer but it felt like cheating a little bit. So, I think it is better that you provided a derivation for it.

Comment: Is there a way to prove to the formula $I_n=e\int_0^\infty \frac{t^ne^{-t}}{n!} J_0(2\sqrt{t})\;\mathrm{d}t$ without using complex analysis?

Comment: @user914367, I also thought about that but was only able to revisit this question now. Anyway, I came up with a new answer, motivated by the old version but not using complex analysis.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear downvoter, would you kindly point out why my answer is being downvoted, so that I can improve the quality of my question?

Answer (score 10):

Let $I_m=\sum\limits_{n=0}^m \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\dbinom{m}{n}$ and notice that $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-nit} e^{e^{it}} dt  = \frac{1}{n!} \tag{1}$$

This is easily proven by using the power series of the exponential and writing $$e^{e^{it}}=\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{e^{ikt}}{k!}\tag{2}$$
and exchanging sum and integral. Then you notice that all terms but the one for $k=n$ are zero.

With $(1)$, you can then write

$$\begin{split}
I_m&=\frac 1 {2\pi}\sum\limits_{n=0}^m (-1)^n\dbinom{m}{n}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-nit} e^{e^{it}} dt\\
&= \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sum\limits_{n=0}^m (-1)^n\dbinom{m}{n}e^{-nit} e^{e^{it}} dt\\
&= \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(1-e^{-it}\right)^m e^{e^{it}} dt
\end{split}$$
With this, inspired by **@Gary** to sum all the $I_m$'s
$$\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} I_m=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \left(1-e^{-it}\right)^m\right) e^{e^{it}} dt = \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{it} e^{e^{it}} dt=0$$
where again, we get $0$ because you can use $(2)$ and observe that all terms of the series are non-constant (integer) powers of the complex exponential, which all integrate to $0$ over $(-\pi, \pi)$.

Thus $$\boxed{\lim_{m\rightarrow+\infty}I_m= 0}$$

**Additional notes**: My previous answer also showed that the following recurrence formula holds:

$$(m+1)I_{m+1}-2mI_m+mI_{m-1}=0$$
which can be useful for fast numerical computation of the $I_m$'s (each is computed in $\mathcal O(1)$ steps instead of $\mathcal O(m)$ with the original formula).

And if you consider the generating function $f(z)=\sum_{m\geq 0}I_m z^m$, the recurrence relation above proves that $(z-1)^2f^\prime(z)+zf(z)=0$,
which implies that $f(z)=\frac{C}{1-z}e^{\frac 1 {z-1}}$ with $C=f(0)e=e$.

Comment: $\imath$ is $i$ ?

Comment: I fixed that and added a full answer to the question.

Comment: $\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} I_m=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \left(1-e^{-it}\right)^m\right) e^{e^{it}} dt$ How do you justify the exchange of order of integral and summation here? We don't (and shouldn't) have absolute convergence here. See [Failure of Fubini's theorem for non-integrable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini's_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions).

Comment: Yeah I might have gone a bit fast on this one, it's not as simple as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia the Laguerre polynomials can be defined as

$$L_m (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} x^n$$

Hence the sum of the OP is just $L_m(1)$.

The leading term of the asymptotic behaviour for large $m$ is

$$L_m (1)\simeq\sqrt{\frac{e}{\pi }} \sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{m}} \cos \left(2 \sqrt{m}-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$

Hence $\lim_{m\to \infty}L_m(1)=0$.

Comment: The user Gary also pointed out essentially the same asymptotic formula in the comment. Considering that this is a contest problem, are you willing to provide a more self-contained solution, including the proof of the asymptotic formula?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the posed problem is much more difficult. So here my solution.

The given formula can be identified as

$LaguerreL(m,1)$.

In words this is the formula of a Laguerre L polynomial for degree $m$ evaluated at the point $x=1$!

$LaguerreL(m,1)=\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\binom{m}{n}$

as required. This identity can be easily verified over at Wolfram Alpha Pro.

This is already a short notation for $L^{0}_{m}(1)=L(m,0,1)$.

Let us calculate some values to get an idea of what is going on:

m      value of the alternating sum
0.        1
5000      -0.0823773
10000     -0.0250789
15000      0.0536988
20000      0.0606476

So this is neither only negative or positive. For smaller $m$ is has periods of increase and decrease. That is really confusing for the proposal of behavior for very large values.

For m a million this is still not smaller. It is 0.0116919.

So discreteness is contraproductive for making an impression.

Better is a plot:

[image: graph of the given series over continuous m]

From this plot follows that is should be possible to Fourier transform the series and look at the Fourier transform for the behaviour for large m.

The problem is for very small m the function does not behave nice.

Now take the comparable function that has already been mentioned in a different context of this question answers and look:

[image: compare the approximation to the orginal function series]

With this graphical or visual prove it gets clear what [Dr. Wolfgang-Hintze](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/198592/dr-wolfgang-hintze) intended but did not prove or even answer.

From very small values of m to very large the compare cosine is very close to the series under treatment. We are allowed with this match to replace our numerical experiments with the functions values of the trigonometric approximation.

It follows for every $m$ the approixmation is close to the numerial result for the series even for very large $m$. This is consequence of the attribute that trigonometric function are a complete space for approximations see for example the Fourier Approximation theory.

$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}L(m,0,1)=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{cos(\sqrt{m}-\frac{\pi}{4})}{m^{\frac{1}{4}}}=0$

The limit is done over the Laguerre polynoms index in the first component.

The approximation is true for positive and negative values of the series over m and the series sequence converges absolute like the the negative power of one quarter of m to zero.

There is no need to calculate the amplitude since this is close to one. But the phase $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is needed very much because otherwise the cosine would be shifted along the $m$ - axis and this destroys the great visual impression. The frequency is then a big problem. This is not very Fourier but a easy guess after the decision for approximation is made. For proving the identity on $\mathbb R$ in the Fourier approximation theory it is only needed that the approximated function is approxed in a finite intervall as is shown in the graph. The graphs several periods not only one.

The graph too confirms the rather slow convergence to zero.

I think this is a prove and convinces the last one.