# Prove that $ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\binom{n}{k}=e\int_0^\infty \frac{t^ne^{-t}}{n!} J_0(2\sqrt{t})\;\mathrm{d}t$ using only real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, bessel-functions

Here $J_0$ is the [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Yesterday I ask [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330403/prove-that-lim-m-to-infty-sum-n-0m-frac-1nn-binommn-0) on MSE. After some time some answers were given, only one (answer 2) being without mistakes. Then I tried to understand it.
This answer use complex analysis to prove the problem from the title:

> $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\binom{n}{k}=e\int_0^\infty \frac{t^ne^{-t}}{n!} J_0(2\sqrt{t})\;\mathrm{d}t$

(this formula is a special case of https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.10.E9, but here is not presented a proof)

and the problem is that *I don't know complex analysis*. So, I ask for a solution to this problem using *only real analysis.*

**My approach.**
Denote LHS by $I_n$ and RHS by $\mathcal{J}_n$. Then by using power series expansion for $J_0$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{J}_n&=\frac{e}{n!}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2}t^k\;\mathrm{d}t\\&=
\frac{e}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty
               e^{-t}t^{n+k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2}\;\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{e}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{n+k}\;\mathrm{d}t
\\&=\frac{e}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2}\Gamma(n+k+1)\\
&=\frac{e}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2}(n+k)!\\&=
e\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\binom{n+k}{k}.
\end{align*}
Remains to show that $e\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}\dbinom{n+k}{k}=I_n$.

Here I stopped. We have two problems:

1. At the second equality we use Fubini's theorem without knowing that the integral converges.
2. I cannot prove that $I_n=e\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}\dbinom{n+k}{k}$ (here my ideas are to use $e=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant 0}\frac1{n!}$ and Cauchy product of two series).

EDIT. The answer to the question is in the now edited answer 2 [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330403/prove-that-lim-m-to-infty-sum-n-0m-frac-1nn-binommn-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculating the generating function for the LHS has already been done following your link. It suffices to calculate the generating function for the RHS i.e.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathcal{J}_n x^n = e\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \binom{n+k}{k}  = e \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^n \\ = \frac{e}{1-x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{1}{(1-x)^k} = \frac{e}{1-x} \, e^{-\frac{1}{1-x}} \, .$$

Here we used the fact that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} \,.$$

---

Interchanging summation and integration is justified, since $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-t)^k}{k!^2} \right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{t^k}{k!^2} \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!^2} \leq \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{k/2}}{k!} \right)^2 = e^{2\sqrt{t}}$$
for any integer $n$. You can then make use of the DCT.

Answer (score 0):

May be a few identities could help.
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\binom{n}{k}\,x^k=\, _1F_1(-n;1;x)=L_n(x)$$ ($L_n(x)$ being Laguerre polynomial) and
$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, L_n(1) =0$

On the other side, the last expression you wrote
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}\dbinom{n+k}{k}x^k=\, _1F_1(n+1;1;-x)=L_{-n-1}(-x)$$

So, it remains to prove that
$$\, _1F_1(-n;1;1)=e\,\, _1F_1(n+1;1;-1)$$ or that
$$L_n(1)=e\,L_{-n-1}(-1)$$

Both are (numerically) true but, at this point, I am stuck.

Comment: What do you understand by "both are (numerically) true"?

Comment: @user914367. The two equations at the bottom. I must say that I started with these ideas in mind and I don't knwo how to get out of this framework. May be later (age problem, I guess).

Comment: But why for example $L_n(1)=eL_{-n-1}(-1)$ is true?

Comment: @user914367. I wrote *numerically*

Comment: The expression $L_{-n}(x)=e^xL_{n-1}(-x)$ appears here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials

Comment: It seems to me one should be able to prove this expression directly from the differential equation for Laguerre polynomials + their recursion relation.

Comment: [Kummer's transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E39)